# Closing files with dask's from_array function

Tags: python, dask

I happened to use Dask's "from_array" method. As in the docs at https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-creation.html, I do as follows:

```python
>>> import h5py
>>> f = h5py.File('myfile.hdf5') # HDF5 file
>>> d = f['/data/path']          # Pointer on on-disk array
>>> x = da.from_array(d, chunks=(1000, 1000))
```

But in this example, do you agree that I should close the hdf5 file after processing the data?

If yes, it may be useful to add a feature to Dask array to allow to just pass the file pointer and the dataset key in order to include a routine in Dask array that would close the source file, if any, when the dask array object is destroyed.

I know that a good way to proceed would be like this:

```python
>>> import h5py
>>> with h5py.File('myfile.hdf5') as f: # HDF5 file
>>>     d = f['/data/path']          # Pointer on on-disk array
>>>     x = da.from_array(d, chunks=(1000, 1000))
```

But sometimes it is not really handy. For example, in my code, I have a function that returns a dask array from a filepath with some sanity checks in between, a bit like :

```python
>>> import h5py
>>> function get_dask_array(filepath, key)
>>>     f = h5py.File(filepath) # HDF5 file
>>>     # ... some sanity checks here
>>>     d = f[key] # Pointer on on-disk array
>>>     # ... some sanity checks here
>>>     return da.from_array(d, chunks=(1000, 1000))
```

In this case, I find it ugly to return the file pointer as well and keep it aside for the duration of the processing, before closing it.

Any suggestion on how I should do?

Thank you in advance for your answers,

Regards,

Edit: for now I am using a global variables inside a package as follows:

```
@atexit.register
def clean_files():
    for f in SOURCE_FILES:
        if os.path.isfile(s):
            f.close()
```